# Trying to make my JS regex for matching multiple unicode character sets work

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/aM1fU5/7) matches, but I want to modify it to work a bit differently:

```
^[\u0000-\uFFFF]+@[\u0000-\uFFFF]+\.[\u0000-\uFFFF]+$
```

I want to make it slightly more restrictive (I don't want to support multiple @ signs before the first @ sign, and, **I want to also learn how to be able to selectively support different Unicode character ranges**).

The @ sign [is 0x0040](http://unicode-table.com/en/0040/), so I want to filter it out (and eventually other ranges of characters). So for example, I have tried [this](https://regex101.com/r/aM1fU5/8) to filter out 0x0040, but it no longer matches:

```
^[\u0000-\u0039\u0041-\uFFFF]+@[\u0000-\uFFFF]+\.[\u0000-\uFFFF]+$
```

I am sure my regex is off somewhere, so can someone please show me how I can make a regex that supports only characters between `\u0000-\u0039` and `\u0041-\uFFFF` before the first @ sign?

Comment: That's in Hex. Change `0039` to `003F`.

Comment: `\u0000-\u0039` should be changed to `\u0000-\u003F`. After `0039`, you get `003A`, not `0040`.

Comment: @RohitJain Ah, silly me.

Comment: @RohitJain Right, this works: https://regex101.com/r/aM1fU5/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't want it to match **only** if it contains the character with the code of `\u0040` before the first `@`, but you wrote your first "one of" clause as `[\u0000-\u0039\u0041-\uFFFF]`, which means:

> I don't want it to match when it is the character with one of the following codes: `\u003A`, `\u003B`,
>   `\u003C`, `\u003D`, `\u003E`, `\u003F` *or* `\u0040`.

Basically, you're missing that there are not only `\u0040`, but also the other numbers, between `\u0039` and `\u0041` in the hexadecimal system.

The [correct regex](https://regex101.com/r/jI0dA8/2), using the @RohitJain's suggestion, is:

```
^[\u0000-\u003F\u0041-\uFFFF]+@[\u0000-\uFFFF]+\.[\u0000-\uFFFF]+$
```